# Get last record ID from QB PHP wrapper Query

Tags: php, api, quickbase

I am using the PHP quickbase wrapper and I need to get a table's most recent record id.

From the tutorials and other materials I have read, I think you need to set your query up like so:

```
$queries = array(
        array(
            'fid'   => '3',
            'ev'    => 'ex',
            'cri'   => '2')
         );

$results = $quickbase->do_query($queries, '', '', '3');
```

I know the FID I want is 3, I'm unsure what ev to use, as well as how I would phrase my cri to say the last, or highest count record id.

I have tried basic query's against other data and have gotten 0 returns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

When I submit my first record in table A I can grab the rid xml object.

```
$results = $quickbase->add_record($fields);
$rid = $results->rid;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html#getrecordinfo.html

On "responses values" try to get the element name "rid", maybe it will help you?!

Comment: Good idea! I tried that method but it requires an RID... which is what I'm trying to find automatically.

I need the newest rid from table A so I can put data in table B. Table B has a field that relates back to Table A based on RID

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the sort list to use field 3 (&slist=3), and have the options parameter sort in decreasing order and return only one record (the one with the largest [Record ID#]):

```
&slist=3&options=sortorder-D.num-1
```

The query will be "some field contains something":

```
&query={'0'.CT.''}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't SQL we are dealing with.